# Copy multiple Excel ranges to Outlook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using Ron de Bruin's code to copy ranges of multiple Excel worksheets to Outlook. When I transfer the ranges to Outlook, one table has all the values while the other table's values show as errors (#div/0! error).

I couldn't find a way to directly copy two ranges to Outlook, so I used another code to copy these two ranges to a new worksheet and take the range of that new worksheet to Outlook. I've identified the problem as the way I'm transferring these two ranges to a new worksheet:

```
Worksheets("Data1").Range("A2:I29").Copy Destination:=Worksheets(ws1.Name).Range("A1")
Worksheets("DV2").Range("A2:I30").Copy Destination:=Worksheets(ws1.Name).Range("A35")
LastRow = Worksheets(ws1.Name).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
```

My full code:

```vb
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()
    Dim dv As Range
    Dim sfr As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
 
    Set dv = Nothing
    Set sfr = Nothing
    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    Worksheets("Data1").Range("A2:I29").Copy Destination:=Worksheets(ws1.Name).Range("A1")
    Worksheets("DV2").Range("A2:I30").Copy Destination:=Worksheets(ws1.Name).Range("A35")
    LastRow = Worksheets(ws1.Name).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    Set rng = ws1.UsedRange
    On Error GoTo 0
 
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected." & _
            vbNewLine & "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If
   
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
 
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
 
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = ""
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
 
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
 
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
   
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets(ws1.Name).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   
End Sub
 
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook
 
    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"
   
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
 
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
        SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
        Filename:=TempFile, _
        Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
        Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
        HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With
 
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
        "align=left x:publishsource=")
 
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False
 
    Kill TempFile
 
    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Sub SendEmailWithRange()
    Dim MyRange1 As Range,MyRange2 As Range
    Dim doc As Object,x
    
    Set MyRange1 = Worksheets("Data1").Range("A2:I29")
    Set MyRange2 = Worksheets("DV2").Range("A2:I30")
    
    With CreateObject("outlook.application").CreateItem(0)
        .Display
        
        .Body = "This is the body:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
        Set doc = .GetInspector.WordEditor
        
        x = doc.Range.End - 1
        MyRange1.Copy
        doc.Range(x).Paste
            
        x = doc.Range.End - 1
        doc.Range(x) = vbNewLine & vbNewLine
        
        x = doc.Range.End - 1
        MyRange2.Copy
        doc.Range(x).Paste
        
        .To = "someone@somewhere.com"
        .Subject = "My subject"

        'uncomment .Send to send the email immediately
        '.Send
        
        Application.CutCopyMode = 0
    End With
    
End Sub
```